# Special characters not displayed in text/html object

Tags: php, html, special-characters

I am trying to display content from a website with a text/html object like this :

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
</head> 

<object type="text/html" width="735" height="1000"
    data="http://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/dokuwiki/phpincludes/publicationstest.php?abteilung=alle&rev=ja&ajahr=2006&mim=ja">
  <p>you should have seen my other page here, but something broke.</p>
</object>
```

However, special characters are not displayed correctly. I can see, but not edit, the php script creating the output on the server side:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
<html>

<head>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0"; charset=charset=ISO-8859-1>
<title>Publikationen</title>

</head>

<body>
<?php
if ($query['rev'] == "alle") {$OK = true;};
...
?>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Is it possible to get correctly display special characters?

Comment: where are the characters ?

Comment: charset=charset=ISO-8859-1

Comment: I see Ã¤ instead of ä or Ã¼ instead of ü for example

Comment: Changing to charset="ISO-8859-1" on my site does not make a difference!

Answer (score 0):

A flagrant [mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) exemplar.

The [original data](http://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/DokuWiki_en/doku.php?id=sonstiges:publikationen) come from next procedure

- go to (home) page http://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/
- click *Forschung* (= *Research*) in the main horizontal menu;
- click *Publikationen am MIM* (= *Publications*) on right.

All data are `UTF-8` encoded there, see also explicit HTML meta attribute `charset=utf-8` there.

However, those data occur in an *embedded* HTML document *bogusly* and *seemingly* attributed `charset=ISO-8859-1` following next scenario ([invalid HTML markup code](https://validator.w3.org/)):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    ...
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2//EN">
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft FrontPage 4.0"; charset=charset=ISO-8859-1>
        <title>Publikationen</title>
      </head>
      <body>
        ...
        ...       UTF-8 encoded data bogusly attributed `charset=ISO-8859-1`
        ...
      </body>
    </html>
    ...
  </body>
</html>
```

On the other hand, you are displaying partial content (that [embedded HTML document](http://www.meteo.physik.uni-muenchen.de/dokuwiki/phpincludes/publicationstest.php?abteilung=alle&rev=ja&ajahr=2006&mim=ja)) extracted from the original website. Unfortunately, in its content are some `UTF-8` characters (see e.g. sample data in your comment) misinterpreted as follows:

```
char  encoding     code        name
ü     UTF-8        0xC3 0xBC   LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS
Ã     ISO-8859-1   0xC3        latin capital letter a with tilde
¼     ISO-8859-1        0xBC   vulgar fraction one quarter

ä     UTF-8        0xC3 0xA4   LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH DIAERESIS
Ã     ISO-8859-1   0xC3        latin capital letter a with tilde
¤     ISO-8859-1        0xA4   currency sign
```

due to `charset=UTF-8` encoded data are `charset=ISO-8859-1` interpreted.